# Issue with Keras input array when implementing Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation, keras-layer

I'm trying to implement a convolutional neural network within Keras using a TF backend for image segmentation of 111 images of size 141 x 166. When I run the code below, I get the error message:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_36 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (88, 141, 166, 1)

My X_train variable is the shape (88, 141, 166, 1) as well as the y_train variable. My X_test variable is the shape (23, 141, 166, 1) as well as the y_test variable, as split by the function train_test_split from sklearn.

I'm not sure what the error message means as per **dense_36**. I have tried using the Flatten() function before fitting the model, but it says that I have a ndim = 2 and cannot be flattened.

```
# set input
batch_size = 111
num_epochs = 50
img_rows = 141
img_cols = 166
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
num_classes = img_rows*img_cols

# split training and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_train.astype('float32')

# CNN itself
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', 
input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# compile CNN
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit CNN
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, 
verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

My model summary is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_35 (Conv2D)           (None, 139, 164, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_36 (Conv2D)           (None, 137, 162, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling (None, 68, 81, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_35 (Dropout)         (None, 68, 81, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_28 (Flatten)         (None, 352512)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 128)               45121664  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_36 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258       
_________________________________________________________________
Total params: 45,140,738
Trainable params: 45,140,738
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Can you print the shape of X_train for us?

Comment: The code and the summary do not completely agree with each other. In the code you give the final dense layer ```img_rows*img_cols``` but in the summary it is 2?